# Synology Web Clipper - quick capture mode, what is this?

Tags: nas, google-chrome-extensions, synology

What is the purpose of the 'quick capture mode' in the [Synology Web Clipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/synology-web-clipper/pcfbfimijgibligmbglggnbiobgjgmbk)?

Comment: [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: If you carry on posting answers as questions you will soon be question banned as well.

Comment: You can't be automatically banned from answering because of your *question* history. It also takes more than one poor-quality answer to trigger an answer ban. It's likely that you have some deleted content, which still counts.

Comment: @BenN, that's the point and as long I cannot even answer/solve my own question I'm not able to get out of this vicious circle. The misery started as I wanted to answer my Excel question, offering a very good summery how arrays work in Excel...

Comment: @Stefan It's difficult to offer more productive advice when your answers are deleted and we can't see them to offer suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to get the answer from Synology support but finally I got. Since is not mentioned in their help or KB I will share the information here.

> After this option ticked, it will remember what capture mode that you
>   chose, Simplified or Full or others. the pop out setting frame will
>   not appear again.
>
> If you want to disable it, right click on Web clipper icon and choose
>   setting, it can be disabled in there.